# How to build a scalable architecture?

Tags: значения, информатика

Another IT question. I looked at [yandex](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&clid=1955453&win=451&from=ntp&&lr=10522)
For scalable architecture,shows us

```
масштабируемая архитектура
```

I need this:

How to build scalable architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be translated as: `Как построить масштабируемую архитектуру?`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, as per [reverso.net](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/Scalable) this can be translated as: `Как построить расширяемую архитектуру?`